# Creating website to run database unit tests

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio, t-sql

I've created unit tests using SQL Server data tools in Visual Studio 2013 (cs project). Has anyone created a website which calls these unit tests? It seems rather annoying that VS doesn't have an option which allows you to export to a webpage. It doesn't quite make sense that the solution needs to be opened every time unit testing is required.

Comment: Why would you unit test outside of your development environment? Like building a house then walking down the street to test the nails...

Comment: I agree with @Volvox. "every time unit testing is required" should be, every time you changed code that is the test subject of the unit test. Wouldn't you use VS.Net to make these modifications?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server Unit Tests, please have a look at [Running SQL Server Unit Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851226%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).
It describes various ways to perform the tests, including a command line tool **MSTest.exe**.